# How do you make a Python input loop read and update list item

Tags: python, list, loops

I am making a program that requires an input loop that reads from a previous list and uses that data in the user prompt. I can't find how to make the loop display the next list item on each loop.

I have tried different things but haven't got it to work. I have it set now as just itemName0 but want to have it go up till the loop ends (`itemName1`, `itemName2` etc...)

Item names (`itemName0`,`itemName2`,etc...)

```
for x in range(itemNum):
    globals()['itemName%s' % x] =input("Enter item name: ")

#Item Values (itemValue0,itemValue1,...)
for x in range(itemNum):
    globals()['itemValue%s' % x] =float(input("Enter value for "+(itemName0)+(": ")))
```

I'm hoping to get to this:

```
Enter item name: Pants
Enter item name: Shirts
Enter item name: socks

Enter value for Pants: 
Enter value for Shirts:
Enter value for socks:
```

I need the loop to run for however the length of the user inputs as `itemNum` but update the items for the names.

Comment: Python 3.6+ has [formatted string literals (f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) that make most string formatting tasks  easier: `'itemName%s' % x` becomes `f'itemName{x}'`

Comment: Just append `'itemName%s' % x` to a list and iterate over the list.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables

Answer (score 2):

The next line is wrong:

> `globals()['itemValue%s' % x] =float(input("Enter value for "+(itemName0)+(": ")))`

Note, `itemName0` is always the first item. This must be variable. I replaced this and works for me:

```py
for x in range(itemNum):
    globals()['itemValue%s' % x] =float(input("Enter value for "+(globals()['itemName%s' % x])+(": ")))
```